# Ubuntu 19.10 64-bit on Raspberry PI 4: How to unlock 100 MGz as min cpu frequency?

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, sysfs

Is there way to unlock min cpu frequency for Ubuntu 19.10 64-bit for raspberry pi?

First, this linux does't have /boot/config.txt similar to raspbian or ubuntu 18.04 from berryboot

Next, the following code has no effect

```
root# echo 100000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/cpuinfo_min_freq
```

As a developer I need to test a heavy multithreaded code on a range of online cores with different CPU freq

I need to find a way to downclock CPU freq from 600 MHz down to 100 MHz (similar to raspbian)

P.S. I'm using official image from https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

P.P.S. Also I need to switch off online cores using `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu{1,2,3}/online` files. But it does not work and kernel does not support it:

```
root@ubuntu /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3 $ echo 0 > online
-bash: echo: write error: Operation not supported
```

Comment: `But it does not work and kernel does not support it` - so, you know that's not possible

Comment: I don't think the the cpu clock of the RPI4 can be changed. Where did you get that information?

Comment: @PMF, take a look at official config.txt for raspbian: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/overclocking.md

`arm_freq_min=100`

Comment: “ As a developer I need to test a heavy multithreaded code on a range of online cores with different CPU freq” - this might buy you false security. Race condition bugs are notoriously hard to provoke on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

the raspberry's config.txt in ubuntu is located at /boot/firmware/config.txt, you can use it to specify range min max in the hardware, and then use cpufrequtils in ubuntu to actually set the cpu freq